# Размер текста в TextView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать возможность того, чтобы в одной строке TextView использовался обычный текст и "ЖИРНЫЙ" текст. Сейчас использую данный способ:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/razmer0"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/2"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Razmer1"/>
```

в java- коде прописываю следующее:

```
    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.1);
    en_text1.setText("123");
    TextView en_text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.2);
    en_text2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    en_text2.setText("456");
```

Если делать таким способом, то в первой строке будут обычные цифры 123, а в следующей строке будут "жирные" цифры 456. Вопрос заключается лишь в том, как можно сделать (и можно ли вообще) чтобы 123(простые) и 456(жирные) были на одной строке. Если говорить по-другому, то как сделать так чтобы в обычном тексте можно было выборочно сделать "жирные" слова и при этом не происходил переход на следующую строку?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533512/3212712):

```
 TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.1);
 en_text1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "жирный" + "</b>" + 
        "<small>" + "маленький" + "</small>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так еще, через spannable

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("HELLOO");

    final StyleSpan boldSpanStyle= new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
    final StyleSpan normalSpanStyle = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
    sb.setSpan(boldSpanStyle, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    sb.setSpan(normalSpanStyle, 4, 6, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо условие на изменение стиля шрифта конкретного слова, то вот:
(работает с любыми символами и цифрами)

```
String text="Ваш текст";
Spannable span1 = new SpannableString(text); //основной (для вывода текста)
Spannable span2 = new SpannableString(text); //изменяемый (нужен для цикла)
String path="текст"; //слово которое необходимо изменить
int startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path); //получаем начальный индекс слова в тексте

while (startIndexOfPath!=-1) { //если есть совпадение по тексту, то выполняется цикл:

span1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), //меняем стиль слова на "жирный"
              startIndexOfPath, startIndexOfPath + path.length(), 0);

StringBuilder sTextBuilder = new StringBuilder(span2); //создаем StringBuilder

//заменяем найденное слово на любые другие символы в таком же кол-ве как само слово
//например в слове текст 5 символов, поэтому меняем на 5 других символов 
//(нужно если в тексте несколько совпадений)

sTextBuilder.replace(startIndexOfPath, startIndexOfPath + path.length(),"12345");

span2=new SpannableString(sTextBuilder); //присваиваем измененный текст

startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path); //снова получаем начальный индекс слова в тексте
}

textView.setText(span1); //выводим в textView конечный результат
```

Спасибо за внимание. Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный.